# How to install zsh shell in centos 8

Tags: zsh, centos8

In **centos** 8 packages, there is no **zsh**.

I tried to install it with yum:

```
yum install zsh
```

It returns the following message:

```
No match for argument: zsh
Error: Unable to find a match: zsh
```

How to install it with yum/dnf?

Comment: Does `yum list all` show zsh as available package?

Comment: At least in the CentOS 8 Docker image, `yum install zsh` works fine. `zsh-5.5.1-6.el8_1.2.x86_64` is in the BaseOS repository.

Comment: I installed the CentOS 8 AppStream version. **yum list all | grep zsh** only give me a list of: `cekit-zsh-completion.noarch`, `zsh-html.noarch` and `zsh-syntax-highlighting.noarsh`